# Any Python function that helps upload images from local to Strapi?

Tags: image, upload, strapi

I'm looking for a python script / example that can upload a image from my local directory to Strapi. I'm very new to Strapi ^^' Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:1337/upload'

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer your_jwt'}

_file = {'files': ('filename.jpeg', open('filename.jpeg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}

r = requests.post(url, files=_file, headers=headers)
```

**For uploading images with content creation, read this:**
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4264#issuecomment-646767130

Comment: Hi Prince Shaji, thank you for your help ! The code worked correctly, but when I opened my Media Library the image did not show up. Do we need something to add to the code ? Thanks and have a nice day !

Comment: @vinimisu I have a much more detailed explanation on a similar issue in the link below. Feel free to check it out. https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4264#issuecomment-646767130

Comment: my script is working perfectly on entry creation !! Thanks alot for the link mate  !

Comment: @vinimisu I was looking for a strapi library for python and since there isn't one on pypi, I decided to build one myself. I hope it will be ready in the next month or so, depending on the free time I get. Feel free to follow this project on GitHub. https://github.com/PrinceShaji/strapi-sdk-python